# speed up img loading

Tags: javascript

I have an array of images which pre-load and I have nine img tags on my page.
I want to randomly replace and scramble the nine imgs with images from the array when i hover over a button.
this all works but, it runs slowly, the imgs re-load the src. how do i

```
var arrayImg = new Array();

arrayImg[0] = new Image();

<img id="img0" >
```

then do:

```
document.getElementbyID("img0").src = arrayImg[random_ndx].src;
```

there are 9 images.

I am running ie8 on a new fast pc but there is a very noticeable lag in the images changing. So, my question; how do I assign a cached image (arrayImg[random_ndx]) directly to an element () on the page?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate, see if the url helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild).

```
local old = document.getElementbyID("img0")
old.parent.replaceChild(arrayImg[random_ndx], old)
```

Note that any element can't be in more than one place on page, so if you place element from `arrayImg` somewhere and then use it to replace another image you won't have two images, it will move from its previous location to new instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the images and make them hidden. Then you need the hidden image to display. That's how I would simulate a cached array.